# Getting "assignment to undeclared variable" error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to use a react icon picker using [material-ui-icon-picker](https://github.com/DMDc0de/material-ui-icon-picker)

But, I get an **assignment to undeclared variable showPickedIcon** error

```
edit( { attributes, className, focus, setAttributes, setFocus, setState  } ) {
     const { content, alignment ,applyStyles,icon} = attributes;
     showPickedIcon = (icon) => {
         console.info(icon) // prints {name: "access_alarm", code: "e190"}
     }

     return (
         <MaterialUiIconPicker onPick={this.showPickedIcon} />
     );
},
```

and I can't find how to fix this.

Comment: Your variable `showPickedIcon` is not defined in the scope. Declare it with `const`, `let` or `var` and you won't have that error. Also, refrain from asking such low level questions which can be solved using a good IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

showPickedIcon is not declared, so give it a declaration, like this:

```
edit( { attributes, className, focus, setAttributes, setFocus, setState  } ) {
        const { content, alignment ,applyStyles,icon} = attributes;
        const showPickedIcon = (icon) => {
        console.info(icon) // prints {name: "access_alarm", code: "e190"}
    }


        return (
                <MaterialUiIconPicker onPick={this.showPickedIcon} />
                );
    },
```

Comment: Please make sure you point such silly mistakes in the comments rather than answering them in full.